# How do you replace all instances of a pattern with a specific string?

Tags: php, regex

Given the following ...

```
$rows = [
    'Blah *-*-*-*-*-*-*-* Blah',
    'Blah *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-* Blah',
    'Blah *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-* Blah',
];
```

... how would I replace that crappy repeating pattern of unknown length with `***`, so the result would be ...

```
$result = [
   'Blah *** Blah',
   'Blah *** Blah',
   'Blah *** Blah',
];
```

I'm entirely unclear on how repeating patterns work in regex. I tried

```
foreach ($rows as $r) {
    echo preg_replace('/[\*\-]{3,}/', '***', $r) .'<br>';
}
```

and a number of other variations. Is this an easy thing?

EDIT: I spent 30 minutes scouring stackoverflow for an answer, but found it difficult enough figuring out what question to ask. I could find no relevant answer. So any help framing the question would be appreciated as well :)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `preg_replace('/\*\-{3,}/', '***', $string)`

Comment: ```preg_replace_all('/\*\-{3,}/', '***', $string)```

Comment: What is `$string`? How does it relate to `$rows`?

Comment: $string is a single element in the array.

Comment: @futureweb There's no such thing as `preg_replace_all`!

Comment: You have to assign the result of `preg_replace()` back to the array element, it doesn't modify in place.

Comment: Show your whole code that loops over the array and tries to update it.

Comment: @Barmar Done ...

Comment: @neokio Haha no there isn't :D preg_match_all silly sausage !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give an array to `preg_replace()` and it will perform the replacement in all the array elements. It returns a new array of the results, it doesn't modify the array in place.

To match `*` followed by `-`, use `\*-`, not `[\*\-]`. The latter matches a single character that's either `*` or `-`.

```
$result = preg_replace('/(\*-){3,}\*/', '***', $rows);
```

Comment: Oh right, I forgot you could simply provide an array of strings as the subject. Nice.

Comment: @Barmar but you would get **** not ***

Comment: Should the regex not be: `/([*-]){3,}/`? Your suggestion leaves a trailing `*` in the replacement?

Comment: I added another `*` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: `[*-]{3,}` would match `*****` or `-----`, it doesn't require them to alternate.

Comment: Would `/(\*-?){3,}/` accomplish the same thing, making the final `-` optional?

Comment: That makes all the `-` optional.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would solve it...

```
<?php

$rows = [
    'Blah *-*-*-*-*-*-*-* Blah',
    'Blah *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-* Blah',
    'Blah *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-* Blah',
];

array_walk($rows, function (&$row)
{
    $row = preg_replace('/^(.*) [*-]+ (.*)$/', '$1 *** $2', $row);
});
```

`[*-]+` is telling the regex to find any number of `*` or `-` characters.

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Blah *** Blah
    [1] => Blah *** Blah
    [2] => Blah *** Blah
)
```

[Regex101.com Sandbox](https://regex101.com/r/NdffRb/1)